# VS copies a dependent dll without build events

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, dependencies

I have some weird pre-build behaviour in visual studio that I would like to figure out.

A single Visual Studio 2008 Solution contains:

- a native c++ library project,
- a managed c++/cli library project (wrapper for the native project)
- a c# console project (using the cli wrapper)

The managed c++/cli project has a dependency on the native c++ project,
and the c# project has a dependency on the c++/cli project.
The dependencies are all targeted on projects, not the individual dlls.

In debug mode all works well. If I execute the main c# project, all dependent projects are checked for changes, recompiled, and the native dll is copied to the respective output directories.

In release mode, the native dll is not copied automatically.

I know I can manually define a post-build event to copy the dll, but why is it automatically copied in debug mode? There are no pre- or post-build events defined in any of the projects.

What black magic makes this work automatically in debug mode but not in release mode?

---

(addendum)

Here is an excerpt from the build log for the debug mode:

```
2>------ Neues Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: CppManaged, Konfiguration: Debug Win32 ------
2>Die Zwischen- und Ausgabedateien für das Projekt "CppManaged" mit der Konfiguration "Debug|Win32" werden gelöscht.
2>Kopieren von "c:\LocalProjects\mysolution\UnmanagedCpp\Debug\unmanaged.dll" in das Zielverzeichnis...
2>Kopieren von "c:\LocalProjects\mysolution\UnmanagedCpp\Debug\unmanaged.pdb" in das Zielverzeichnis...
2>Kompilieren...
2>Stdafx.cpp
2>Kompilieren...
...
```

And here is the same log for release mode:

```
2>------ Neues Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: CppManaged, Konfiguration: Release Win32 ------
2>Die Zwischen- und Ausgabedateien für das Projekt "CppManaged" mit der Konfiguration "Release|Win32" werden gelöscht.
2>Kompilieren...
2>Stdafx.cpp
2>Kompilieren...
...
```

In debug mode the dll and pdb file get copied, yet there is no pre- or post-build event defined for this.

Comment: For many years I have been dealing with solutions with native, managed and C++/CLI projects. I've never been able to work out the "black magic" and have come to rely on build events.

Answer (score 0):

Check your build configuration via Build -> Configuration Manager.

Select Release from the Active solution configuration.

All your projects should be selected in both build and release (the build column).

Comment: They are all selected, and if I click on rebuild, they will all be built. But in debug the respective dlls get copied between the different target directories, and in release they are not